# Can I ask a question regarding the history of television?

Tags: support, scope

I'm a newcomer at this stackexchange site and I haven't found the site guidelines and the kind of questions which are supposed to be asked. I wanted to ask a question regarding when a particular technology was introduced in certain country and this is regarding television. i.e Which was the first HDTV program aired in Taiwan? or let's say What are the shortwave frequencies to tune NHK radio?. Is it okay to ask these questions here?.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: We don't get a lot of questions like these .... but the first one looks like it might be on topic.  The second one relates to radio, so would not be on topic.

Comment: I have a vague recollection of a similar question about HD in Japan sometime back. Can't find it now or it it had an answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D So does this means Can I post such question or...? Excluding the radio thing, although I'm curious if I were to ask for those details which place could be the right way to do so?

Comment: Sure...I'm not sure you'll get an answer though but you never know. Frankly I think it more likely to get an answer from a proper Google Search